# Не проходит POST-запрос в C# asp net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp

Есть модель данных:

```
public class AccrualPayment
{
    public string OIDobject { get; set; }
    public string PersonalAccount { get; set; }
    public string IdAccrual { get; set; }
    public string DateAccrual { get; set; }
    public string SummAccrual { get; set; }
    public string DatePayment { get; set; }
    public string SummPayment { get; set; }

    public AccrualPayment(string oidObject, string personalAccount, string idAccrual, string dateAccrual, string summAccrual, string datePayment, string summPayment)
    {
        OIDobject = oidObject;
        PersonalAccount = personalAccount;
        IdAccrual = idAccrual;
        DateAccrual = dateAccrual;
        SummAccrual = summAccrual;
        DatePayment = datePayment;
        SummPayment = summPayment;
    }
}
```

Есть контроллер принимающий POST-запрос с параметром - объект модели данных:

```
public class FileApiController : ApiController
{
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/FileApi/uploadData")]
        public void UploadData([FromBody] AccrualPayment [] accrualPayment)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
           ...
        }
}
```

На странице фронта ajax запрос отправляющий массив json на сервер в теле запроса:

```
$(".uploadData").click(async function () {
                var data = await ExcelToJSON('AccrualsPaymentsSocialRent');
                if (data != undefined & data.length > 0){
                    data = data[0];
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost:6141/api/FileApi/uploadData",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    processData: false,
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    error: function (result, status, er) {
                        alert("error: " + result + " status: " + status + " er:" + er);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Запрос почему-то не проходит - при отладке до тчк остановы в контроллере не доходит, а среда разработки выдает сообщение:

> В потоке не запущен совместимый код
>
> Выбранный модуль отладки не поддерживает выполнение любого кода в
> текущем потоке (например, выполняется только машинный код среды
> выполнения). Вы можете переключиться на другой поток, чтобы проверить,
> выполняется ли совместимый код.

Содержимое отправляемого json-массива:

```
data: Array(3)
0: {OIDobject: "aaa13548", PersonalAccount: "00000000001", "IdAccrual ": "00aa00bb01", DateAccrual: "2021.05.21", SummAccrual: "3333", …}
1: {OIDobject: "bbb5433", PersonalAccount: "00000000002", "IdAccrual ": "00aa00bb02", DateAccrual: "2021.05.21", SummAccrual: "2222", …}
2: {OIDobject: "ccc02143", PersonalAccount: "00000000003", "IdAccrual ": "00aa00bb03", DateAccrual: "2021.05.21", SummAccrual: "4444", …}
length: 3

{
    "OIDobject": "aaa13548",
    "PersonalAccount": "00000000001",
    "IdAccrual ": "00aa00bb01",
    "DateAccrual": "2021.05.21",
    "SummAccrual": "3333",
    "DatePayment": "2021.05.21",
    "SummPayment": "1111"
}
```

Сервис на Framework 4.5

Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
```

Файл Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <!--
    Описание изменений web.config см. по адресу http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    Следующие атрибуты можно установить с помощью тега <httpRuntime>.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Попытался переименовать поля в JSON, чтобы они начинались с символа нижнего регистра - выдало ошибку:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://localhost:6141/api/FileApi/uploadData' from origin
> 'https://localhost:44367' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Ведать запрос проходит уже доходит до сервера, но сервер его блокирует, хотя у меня в контроллере указано:

```
 HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Comment: JSON содержимое покажете?

Comment: @aepot, да, дополнил вопрос

Comment: Покажите, как вы настроили WebApi в файле Global.asax. Взгляните на [статью METANIT](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet_webapi/1.1.php), там обратите внимание на секцию `Маршрутизация в Web API`

Comment: Цитата из статьи: Чтобы задействовать маршрутизацию Web API, в файле Global.asax в метод Application_Start() добавляется следующая строка: GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, дополнил вопрос  содержимым Global.asax

Comment: @Vlad-i-mir Покажите еще класс WebApiConfig

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, есть такая там строка, я её не добавлял, ведать при создании проекта она самасформировалась

Comment: @Vlad-i-mir насколько я помню, по дефолту для Web API C# свойство `OIDobject` после сериализации в JSON должно быть такое `oIDobject` (первая буква в нижнем регистре). Возможно, я ошибаюсь

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, WebApiConfig в проекте нет, есть Web.config, дополнил вопрос его содержимым

Comment: @AndreiKhotko,  попытался переименовать поля в JSON, чтобы они начинались с символа нижнего регистра - дополнил вопрос. Ведать запрос проходит, но сервер его блокирует, хотя у меня в контроллере указано ```HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124699/discussion-between-andrei-khotko-and-vlad-i-mir).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по ошибке, у вас для Web Api сервера не настроен CORS. То, что вы написали в контроллере:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

должен делать Middleware до попадания в метод обработки запроса. CORS в ASP.NET Web Api реализован и доступен "из-под капота".

Чтобы включить CORS, вам нужно установить nuget-пакет `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` и в метод `WebApiConfig.Register` добавить `EnableCors`. Есть два немного разных способа добавления CORS:

1. Добавить CORS для всех api-контроллеров;
2. Добавить CORS для нужного контроллера/метода.

**Способ №1**

Требует лишь одного изменения в `WebApiConfig.Register`:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*")
        {
            SupportsCredentials = true // По дефолту, false. Если cross-origin запрос должен отправлять еще и данные для аутентификации (например, Cookie), то нужно выставить это поле в true
        };
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

По сути, этот способ добавляет к каждому api-контроллеру и api-методу CORS policy (действует так же, будто бы мы написали для каждого api-контроллера атрибут `[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*", SupportsCredentials = true)]`)

**Способ №2**

В `WebApiConfig.Register`:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableCors();

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

И в `FileApiController.cs`

```
public class FileApiController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*", SupportsCredentials = true)]
    [Route("api/FileApi/uploadData")]
    public void UploadData([FromBody] AccrualPayment [] accrualPayment)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Подробнее про `EnableCors` можно почитать в документации Microsoft: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api